# Set models fields programmatically in django

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6

I'm making some scripts to migrate an old database to a new one in a `Django` app. In order to manage the data from some tables of the old_app It would be easier to store the id of these tables on a temporary column in the new database.

**Note:** I have to make individual scripts for each table in the `new_app`

For example, suppose I have 2 tables (`A, B`) in the **old_app** with a ManyToMany Relationship. First I made an script to store `A` data and then `B`. Later on I have to store the relantionship between them but I have lost the `id` of both tables as I don't need them in my `new_app`.

**The question is:** Is it possible in `django` to create some kind of temporary column to store the old `id` and then delete that column when I have saved the old relationship?

Something like

```
A.objects.add_column('temporary_id', Models.CharField, ....)
A.objects.delete_column('temporary_id')
```

Or do I have to make a migration of the model before and after I migrate the data from the `old_app`?

Comment: You can make a migration adding the `temporary_id`, perform the transfer, and then another migration that removes the column.

Comment: I know I can do that, the point is I want it all to be automatic so I can run all scripts in a specific order without having to rebuild the models everytime I test a migration

Comment: But in case you would use a hypothetical `add_column` you would also rebuild the models. After all this is translated in a database call. And by using migrations, you can force the migrations to run in a specific order. You can thus create three files `001_add_tmp_id.py`, `002_do_migrationpy`, and `003_remove_tmp_id.py`. We thus can use the `002_do_migration` to perform some migration tasks.